# Acunetix Unable to connect to server

Tags: iis, testing, automated-tests

I am using Acunetix tool to scan my website but gives an error cannot connect to the website. I am trying to connect to my local host. But it keeps on throwing me this error

```
04.11 10:53.48, [Error] Server "http://192.168.24.199/" is not responsive.
04.11 10:53.48, [Error] Response body length exceeds configured limit
```

Its a .Net website running on IIS

Any suggestions  will be appretiacted

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that the HTTP response body length exceeds Acunetix's maximum configured limit.

To change this, navigate to Configuration > Scan Settings > HTTP Options and change the 'HTTP response size limit in kilobytes' to a larger value.

[image]

**Note --** Having said this, I would look into why your app is returning a response body larger than 5MB (Acuentix's default limit), it's not normal to have such large responses (Acunetix automatically ignores common file types like PDFs, images, spreadsheets...).